# InnoDB restore from ibdata: "mysql post-start process terminated with status 1"

Tags: mysql, innodb

I discovered way too late that the backup script for our MySQL databases wasn't working properly. Namely, when the disk on the server had already started to fail, and I logged in via SSH and got a screen-full of corrupted binary rubbish. Restoring from the meagre backups that weren't just empty .sql.gz files would loose us about a month's data. I'd really love it if I can avoid that scenario.

I've been able to fsck the disk and have extracted the contents of the `/var/lib/mysql` directory, with a 100MB `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile*` files and `.frm` and `.opt` files for each database under subdirectories. I don't have `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, everything under there seems to be lost. There are no .ibd files, presumably because innodb_file_per_table was turned off.

I got a MySQL 5.5 install (same version as failed) up on my development machine and attempted to restore the files, following the suggestions [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,47078,51428#msg-51428), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115681/mysql-innodb-database-restore). I put the `ibdata1` and .frm and .opt files into `/var/lib/mysql` set the permissions & owner on the files the same as the defaults (some `mysql:mysql`, some `mysql:root`) after I re-created the tables from the schema using the mysql client.

I then ran mysqld with the command:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld –innodb_log_file_size=4128768 –innodb_force_recovery=6
```

It terminates immediately, with no output. A `dmesg | tail` shows a whole bunch of:

```
[  781.937089] init: mysql main process (1819) terminated with status 1
[  781.937127] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

Both `/var/log/mysql.log` and `/var/log/mysql.err` are empty.

I've tried a number of variations on this recovery process theme. I've tried copying the entire recovered mysql data directory into `/var/lib`, I've tried overwriting only `ibdata1` and the database subdirectory with .frm and .opt folders. I've tried with, and without the logfiles, and incrementing the recovery value from 1-6.

If I restore the original mysql directory, mysqld starts up just fine. Apparmor isn't running on the machine (some people had problems with that).

I read on Percona's MySQL Performance Blog that it's possible to restore the data from just the ibdata1 file. I only have 2 tables per database, and I have the schema- but reading the README provided with their recovery tool, it looks like I at least need to be able to start mysql to get information about the tablespace.

Comment: Other links I've looked at (because this is a first post & I don't have 10 rep):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/06/03/a-recovery-trivia-or-how-to-recover-from-a-lost-ibdata1-file/

http://egil.biz/how-to-recover-mysql-data-from-innodb/

Comment: Just a shot-in-the-dark question: Do you have binary logging enabled ?